# pandas get unique value row by rows

Tags: pandas, unique

I like to get unique value by row based on row across multiple columns,

**data example:**

```
col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d
-----------------------
apple|null|apple|null
bob|bob|null|bob
chris|chirs|null|null
```

**expected output:**

```
new_col
-------
apple
bob
chris
```

Comment: Do you mean 'unique' or 'non-null' value?

Comment: both unique and non-null value

Comment: `df.assign(new=df.mode(axis=1))` ?? do you just want the mode across each row?

Comment: `df.assign(new=df.mode(axis=1))` seems not work, find unique name by each row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
data['new_col'] = data.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist())
```

**Example 1:**

```
   col_a col_b  col_c col_d
0  apple   NaN  apple   NaN
1    bob   bob    NaN   bob
```

output:

```
   col_a col_b  col_c col_d  new_col
0  apple   NaN  apple   NaN  [apple]
1    bob   bob    NaN   bob    [bob]
```

**Example 2:**

```
   col_a col_b  col_c col_d
0  apple   bob  apple   NaN
1    bob   bob    NaN   bob
```

output:

```
  col_a col_b  col_c col_d         new_col
0  apple   bob  apple   NaN  [apple, bob]
1    bob   bob    NaN   bob         [bob]
```

**Example 3:**

```
   col_a  col_b  col_c col_d
0  apple    NaN  apple   NaN
1    bob    bob    NaN   bob
2  chris  chris    NaN   NaN
```

output:

```
   col_a  col_b  col_c col_d  new_col
0  apple    NaN  apple   NaN  [apple]
1    bob    bob    NaN   bob    [bob]
2  chris  chris    NaN   NaN  [chris]
```

Comment: I think you should explain what it does

Comment: Here, `dataframe.stack()` basically stacks the dataframe from columns to index(multi-level indexing) and then we are grouping by a particular level(in our case, level=0) and finally applying lambda function to grouped data. Here, in place of `lambda x: x.unique().tolist()`, we can also use `lambda x:list(set(x))`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but that was not for me. The purpose was to improve your answer which lacks an explanation of what it actually does. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just another variation of the answer above. Although I have not tested thoroughly as the first answer, however, it seems to work in this example.
The idea is to use the apply function row-wise (hence axis =1) and get unique values of each row in a list.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['apple','bob'],
                     'col2':[np.nan,'bob'],
                     'col3':['apple',np.nan],
                    'col4':[np.nan,'bob']})
test['new_col'] = test.apply(lambda row: row.dropna().unique(),axis=1)
```

Output

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    new_col
apple   NaN    apple     NaN    [apple]
bob     bob    NaN       bob    [bob]
```

Comment: Thanks  :) for the clarification I edited the answer.

Comment: Another thing, whenever I'm using apply, I like to name the input I receive to tell the reader that I'm iterating through a... row/col (applying from DataFrame), or a value (applying from Series). I think it's clearer than the basic `x` lambda thing -- You can disagree but thought I'd give my 2 cents about this. :)

Comment: I 100% agree with you, that is a good practice to do. Again I made the edit taking your suggestion into account

Answer (score 1):

Alternative idea:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col_a": ["apple", "bob"],
        "col_b": [np.nan, "bob"],
        "col_c": ["apple", np.nan],
        "col_d": [np.nan, "bob"],
    }
) 
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    print(row.T[row.T.notnull()].unique())
```

Comment: As far as I know, you should avoid `.iterrows()` whenever possible.

Comment: @ImCoins answer's is faster (and more idiomatic).

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple apply works.

```
lambda row:row[~row.isna()].unique().tolist(), axis=1
```

This line means that for each row, you will keep only the values that are not equal to `NaN`, take the unique values from them, convert to a list. The axis=1 is probably what you failed to find originally. :)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a' : [1, 2, 3],
    'b' : [np.nan, 5, 6]
})

df['unique'] = df.apply(lambda row:row[~row.isna()].unique().tolist(), axis=1) 
print(df)
#   a    b      unique
#0  1  NaN       [1.0]
#1  2  5.0  [2.0, 5.0]
#2  3  6.0  [3.0, 6.0]
```